# It is possible to solve $\frac{n}{2^n}<4$ directly? i.e by algebraic manipulation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to solve $$\frac{n}{2^n}<4$$ directly ? i.e by algebraic manipulation? 
(If not, what is the reason?)

Comment: Is $n$ an integer?

Comment: Try it this way to show $2^{n+2}>n\; \forall\:n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 4):

We have that$$\frac{n}{2^n}<4\iff n<2^{n+2}.$$ It should be easy to show that the last inequality holds by using induction.

Comment: (+1) And to take it a step above just natural numbers, we have that the RHS is always positive, so the inequality also holds for all real numbers satisfying $n\le 0$. I'm sure some calculus could be used to show that the inequality holds for all real values